# Apache virtual host from GET url

Tags: apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Above is the example of https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts which I've followed to setup some sites. But what I wanna do is basically:

www.example.com?site=mynewsite.com
With htaccess: www.example.com/mynewsite.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com/mynewsite.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com/mynewsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Sadly above doesn't work.

Reason why I wanna do this is because I want to generate a website using database which will be triggered based of URL.

How may I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the obscure *ServerPath* directive, which maps a request to a virtualhost based on the first component of the URL path.